# Фейковая проверка для редакторов или как понять, что она фейковая

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, аудит

Сейчас зашел в **очередь проверок**, в первых ответах было 1 новое сообщение от пользователя, открыл сообщение, увидел, что сообщение очень общее и в стиле "сделайте задачу за меня"

Нажал **правка** и получил белую страницу с сообщением "Вопрос удален" или как-то так...

Тут-то я понял, что это всего лишь проверка на внимательность...
В общем, считаю, что белая страница с сообщением о том, что вопрос удален - это дефект

Предлагаю для таких проверок делать ссылку на правку неактивной

Comment: Это защита от ботов, которые на автомате кликают по результатам, не вчитываясь в текст.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Плохой проверяющий нажал бы "всё хорошо", а просто встретив такой вопрос, прошёл бы мимо.

Хороший проверяющий, когда видит плохой вопрос, пытается *улучшить его правкой*, пишет дельный комментарий автору и/или ставит тревогу на закрытие.

Вы попытались улучшить вопрос. Этим действием вы уже подтвердили свою адекватность как проверяющего, значит аудит практически прошли. Дальше проверять вас нет смысла, поэтому незачем скрывать/деактивировать ссылку, показывать фиктивный вопрос или делать что-то подобное.

Можете спокойно жать то, что нажали бы на настоящем вопросе. :)

Comment: Так ожидаемый результат был таким, что я должен был увидеть сообщение с успешным прохождением проверки, типо поздравляем это была всего лишь проверка(которое было потом, когда я отправил тревогу), а не пустую страницу с сообщением, что вопрос уже удален

Comment: @tCode думаю, это слишком сложная механика. Бывает, видишь в проверке сообщение, которое сам вчера закрывал или удалял. Или не вчера, а пару недель назад. И это нормально, знаю результат потому что уже видел сообщение.

Comment: @tCode цель проверок — отсеять тех, кто слепо тыкает в кнопочки. Эта цель вполне достигается текущим функционалом. Модераторам доступна табличка со статистикой проверок, там можно найти систематически проваливающих аудит и потом отправить им дружеские рекомендации и пару ссылок. А ещё вроде бы автоматический запрет на проверки был за несколько провалов подряд.